# Univariate vs. multivariate gam output

Tags: r, generalized-additive-model, mgcv

I'm new to GAMs and running some univariate and multivariate models in R with mgcv. I'm struggling to understand differences in model output between the uni and mulivariate.

Ex: A plot for a univariate GAM.

```
gam(effect ~s(percent_precip_min_pe_day_smallgrid_precip_FALL, k=4), data=input_data, method="REML")
```

[image]

And this is the plot for the same variable as above, but as one variable in a multivariate gam.

```
gam(effect ~s(percent_precip_min_pe_day_smallgrid_precip_FALL, k=4) + 
             s(mean_fall_spei, k=4) + 
             s(mean_ao_fall, k=4) + 
             s(total_precip_fall, k=4), data = input_data, method = "REML")
```

[image]

Why are the two plots so different? I'm clearly missing something in how GAMs work but can't figure out what.

Comment: Both models are *univariate,* because that term refers to the dimension of the *response.*  I suspect your question is not specific to GAMs or splines but might concern the distinction between *ordinary* regression (one explanatory variable) and *multiple* regression (more than one explanatory variable).  If not, could you explain the special role played by the GAM in your question?

Comment: Really? I've found a few sources that refer to GAMs with multiple predictors and one response as "multivariate". Ex: https://www.nature.com/articles/s41545-020-0077-3

Comment: And how does that help you?